# scale_y_reverse() not working in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to reverse the y axis and put the x axis on top. Everything is working fine but when i try to provide a range of y axis in `scale_y_reverse()` function the y axis got disappeared and show a warning message - `Removed 44 rows containing missing values (geom_point)` Here is my code-

```
ggplot(out,aes(x=self_w,y=self_h,col=log(out$force),xlim(0,593),ylim(0,790)))+  geom_point(size=log(out$force))+
  scale_fill_continuous(low="green",high="red") +scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0,593),expand=c(0,0),position = "top")+
  scale_y_reverse(limits=c(0,790),expand=c(0,0))
```

[Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9cF34iSt6PAc2U5ZnM3U0ZHSDg) is my dataset. If you delete the arguments of `scale_y_reverse()` it will work fine but that's not what i need. Also the color scale is not achanging from `green` to `red`. Can anybody help me to find the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Ah..i forget to mention, before running this i changed all the 0 to 1 by `out$force[out$force==0]=1`  so that log(1) will be zero

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you reverse the axis, you also need to reverse the limits. So change to `scale_y_reverse(limits=c(790,0), expand=c(0,0))`.

A few other things:

1. Change all instances of `out$force` to `force`, as you shouldn't restate the data frame name within `aes`.
2. In `geom_point`, `size=log(force)` should be wrapped in `aes()`.
3. Looking at your data, `force` is often zero, so `log(force)` will be `-Inf` in those cases.